# Print value between commas from text file

Tags: text-processing, awk

How to print a specific value between commas from text file? There are several lines of this type in the file:

```
0.9999899864,0.6666600108,0.00,0.00,0.00,36988,140920,1,150.00,1500.00,1400.00,1300.00,1,0.50,2.00,0.10,1.00,-0.10,1,123.40,1,0.0,8,
```

I want to print the 7th value, it's `140920`

Comment: You have tagged this with `awk`. Did you try any awk command? How did it fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is use `cut` with delimiter set to `,`:

```
$ cut -d',' -f 7 test 
140920
```

(again, assuming the file is called `test`).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk -F "," '{print $7}'`.

For example if the content is in file `test`, then

```
awk -F "," '{print $7}' test
```

Comment: the quotes around the comma are not needed either, `awk -F,` works fine (the comma isn't special to the shell).